# ОШИБКА: Столбец не существует при попытке заполнить таблицу PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Создаю отношение

```
create table ПОТРЕБИТЕЛЬ (
    ИДЕНТИФИКАТОР serial not null primary key,
    НАЗВАНИЕ varchar(50) not null,
    "АДРЕС ЖИТЕЛЬСТВА" varchar(255) not null,
    "СКИДКА, %" smallint check ("СКИДКА, %" >= 0 and "СКИДКА, %" <= 100) not null
);
```

Затем пытаюсь заполнить таблицу, используя значения

```
insert into ПОТРЕБИТЕЛЬ (ИДЕНТИФИКАТОР, НАЗВАНИЕ, "АДРЕС ЖИТЕЛЬСТВА", "СКИДКА, %") values (001, "АО ВАРЯ", "Сормовский", 10);
insert into ПОТРЕБИТЕЛЬ (ИДЕНТИФИКАТОР, НАЗВАНИЕ, "АДРЕС ЖИТЕЛЬСТВА", "СКИДКА, %") values (002, "ГАЗ", "Автозаводский", 7);
insert into ПОТРЕБИТЕЛЬ (ИДЕНТИФИКАТОР, НАЗВАНИЕ, "АДРЕС ЖИТЕЛЬСТВА", "СКИДКА, %") values (003, "МП ВЕРА", "Канавинский", 5);
insert into ПОТРЕБИТЕЛЬ (ИДЕНТИФИКАТОР, НАЗВАНИЕ, "АДРЕС ЖИТЕЛЬСТВА", "СКИДКА, %") values (004, "МП", "Канавинский", 3);
insert into ПОТРЕБИТЕЛЬ (ИДЕНТИФИКАТОР, НАЗВАНИЕ, "АДРЕС ЖИТЕЛЬСТВА", "СКИДКА, %") values (005, "АО СТАЛЬ", "Советский", 0);
```

Возникает ошибка в каждой строчке, якобы столбец не существует, при этом это даже не столбцы а аргументы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у PostgreSQL в двойные кавычки заключаются названия БД, таблиц и столбцов. А строковые значения надо вставлять в **одинарных** кавычках

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: спасибо, спасли от ступора